# What are the names of the columns that are selected in the Select command in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, attributes

What are the names of the columns that are selected in the Select command in SQL? Attributes? (I am aware that these are columns, but can you also call them attributes?)

[image]

Comment: I would call them values. Given a select by definition always results in a set, they are just values of the members of the set. Not really any definitive answer.

Comment: What's wrong with just *the columns* ? Why do you need an extra name for those??

Comment: @AnnaKhan . . . You can call them whatever you like.  Just be sure that however you are talking to understands what you mean.  If you use non-standard terminology, you will spend a lot of time explaining things over and over.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But what's the standard terminology for this lol. I guess maybe there is no widely recognized term for these? 